# Read Global resource file inside controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization, app-globalresources

How can I read global resource file in MVC controller, I am using this code and it is not working

```
 Resources.BillingResource.Error;
```

returns the following exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'Resources' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

My application is MVC 4 and framework 4.5

Please advice

Comment: Can you please double check whether you have the "BillingResource" file within App_GlobalResources folder? Also make sure the build action of this file set to "Content"

Answer (score 0):

Is the resource file loaded in the same project or is on the different project. If its different project , you would have to add the reference to it.

Also check the namespace generated by the cs file of the resource file and reference that in your view or controller.